# How safe is to use mysqli_insert_id() and if not what should I use?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a very simple question I want to know the id of the last query that I inserted in my MySql DB.

It's safe and efficient to use mysqli_insert_id() and if not what should I use?

Comment: Why wouldn't `mysqli_insert_id()` be safe?  That method exists for the reason you want, and it's fine to use it.

Comment: Just keep in mind that it returns the last inserted ID for _your connected session_ only, and that is the only context where it makes sense. Don't try to use it to find the globally last inserted record or max ID if you have concurrent connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the recommended way to retrieve an ID value generated by an insert when using auto-increment. But it has limitations, which are documented. Did you read the documentation?

The `mysqli_insert_id()` function returns the same value that would be returned by the builtin SQL function [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Note that it only works in the same session after you insert and generate an ID. You can't get the last ID generated in a previous session.

So for example it doesn't work at all in phpMyAdmin, because the "shared nothing" nature of PHP is that every query executes in a different session.

It also only works if your primary key is an auto-incrementing key, *and* if your last insert used the auto-increment mechanism. Even if your table has an auto-increment, you can override that by specifying a value. Then the last insert id is meaningless.  Demonstration:

```
mysql> create table t (id serial primary key);

mysql> insert into t set id = 42;

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
```

Why does this return 0? Because my insert did not *generate* an ID, it just used the ID value I specified in the insert.

It only returns the *latest* ID generated. If you do another subsequent insert that generates an ID, it'll return the more recent generated ID.

It doesn't tell you *which table* the ID was generated by. It's up to you to know which table you most recently inserted into, which used auto-increment to generate an ID.

So in conclusion, yes, it's the right function to use, but you do need to understand how it works and you need to know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

> The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query (usually INSERT) on a
> table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If no INSERT
> or UPDATE statements were sent via this connection, or if the modified
> table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this
> function will return zero.

That said, if the table you are persisting  using `mysqli` (INSERT or UPDATE) has a primary key column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute it will be safe to use `mysqli_insert_id()`.